# Teradata Equivalent for Oracle BITMAP INDEX Local store IN

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am a very beginner for Teradata.And I am migrating Oracle queries to Teradata. I have a query like below.

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX <INDEX_NAME> ON <TABLE_NAME>(<COLUMN_NAME>)LOCAL STORE IN(<TABLE_SPACE>);
```

As per understanding, we dont have BITMAP index in Teradata, but how to implement the above in Teradata. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need this index in Teradata.

Bitmap indexes are mainly recommended for low-cardinality data in Oracle and Teradata's optimizer will not use an index if more than approx. 1% of the rows are returned.

You could create a NUSI instead, the perm space needed will be a bit more than 8 bytes per row (10 bytes, if the table is partitioned), collect statistics on it and when you check Explain the optimizer is probably not using it :-)

Btw, you might see a kind of adhoc-bitmap combining multiple NUSIs in Explain: BMSMS (Bit Map Set Manipulation Step)

Answer (score 0):

Teradata supports multilevel partitioning, so you could integrate that attribute as a partitioning criteria.